# Storing Jenkins pipeline job metadata?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way where to store some metadata from Jenkins pipeline job, e.g:

- We have a Jenkinsfile which builds a gradle project, creates docker image and pushes it to google cloud
- Then a "Subjob" is launched which runs integration tests (IT) on that docker image. Subjob receives a couple of parameters (one of them - the generated docker image name)

Now sometimes that IT job fails, and I would like to re-run it from the main job view, so idealy:

- we have a plugin which renders a custom button in blue ocean UI on the main job
- By clicking that button a subjob is invoked again with the same parameters (plugin queries the jenkins api, get params of this job, and resubmits the subjob).

The problem ? How to get/set those parameters. I could not seem to find a mechanism for that, expect artifact storage. I could get away with that by creating a simple json/text file and uploading it as artifact, and then retrieving it in my plugin, but maybe there is a better way?

Stage restart is not coming to Scripted Pipelines so that does not look like ant option.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the Jenkins API to get the details of the build?

https://your_jenkins_url.com/job/job_name/lastBuild/api/json?pretty=true

Instead of lastBuild you can also use the build number or one of lastStableBuild, lastSuccessfulBuild, lastFailedBuild, lastUnstableBuild, lastUnsuccessfulBuild, lastCompletedBuild

There is a parameters key there with all parameter names and values used in the build.

More details on https://your_jenkins_url.com/job/job_name/api/

Also, any reason you can't use the replay button in the IT job?